# switching between regular html and jQuery mobile site acting strange

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, href, url-link

Ok so I have a jQuery mobile form I am working on and at the end of my form I wanted to include a link back to my main site.  Below is the code I used to add the button on to the header on my form.

```
<a href="http://www.myhomepage.com/" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home">Home</a>
```

Weird this is whenever I click this button my home page (which is not a jQuery Mobile page) displays without any css or script markup.  It only displays the raw html view.  If I refresh the page I then can view my home page with the markup I intended.

Does anyone know why something like this would happen?

Comment: add `rel="external"` to anchor.

Comment: Any chance Omar can make an answer out of it and you can accept?